# UILabel set text is drawn over older one during Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I'm having trouble understanding what is going wrong if you can help me it would be great!

I have a `UIlabel` being animated by `UIView AnimationWithDuration` like a marquee... (I need to make this code work, I can't fork something elsewhere please don't provide marquee reps.)

During this animation I set a new text, unfortunately **the former one is not replace but drawn over**. I end up with two text drawn over each other. And if I try to set the text again it's possible that it get cleaned or it's possible that it get a third line drawn over.

I've tried the following code thinking it's probably a thread issue but it doesn't do anything

```
@synchronized (self.songLabel.text) {
    self.songLabel.text = nil;
    self.songLabel.text = [trackItems objectForKey:@"TrackName"];
}
```

I've set my `songLabel` getter and setters as atomic, it does not help either.

I don't know what to try... thank you for your help!

EDIT: Here is the code that take care of the animation

```
- (void)animateSongLabel
{

    if (!self.player.rate) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{

            self.songLabel.left = 25.f;
        }];

        return;
    }

    if (!self.canAnimateLabel) {
        return;
    }
    self.animateLabel = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0. options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

         self.songLabel.left -= 15.f;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        self.animateLabel = YES;

        if (self.songLabel.right < -10.f) {

            self.songLabel.left = 320.f;
        }
        [self animateSongLabel];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Why is it multithreaded? Can you show your label creation code as well as the animation block entirely.

Comment: I've edited my post. The label is instantiated in the viewController xib file. If you have an idea thank you!

Comment: As far as I know UILabel doesn't allow you to set "left" as a property. Are you using a different subclass?

Comment: yes I use a UIView+helper it doesn't do anything special, just simplify frame modification, it's pretty neat make the code clean. if you want it i can share it